# Update custom function automatically

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, custom-function

I have a custom function as a Google Spreadsheet script, which depends on some other cells' values. It runs ok the first time I put it in a cell, but then when I change the data in the other cells it stays the same. How can I make the first cell update its value automatically when I change the other cells?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an answer which doesn't fully make me happy but it's good enough I guess.
If you add a function called `onEdit` to the script of a spreadsheet, it will be called every time stuff is edited. So, this is the code that worked for me: (it has some details that could be useful so I left them unedited)

```
function onEdit(event) {
  if (SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getName().substr(0,5) == "thing")
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange("I1").setValue(myCustomFunction());
}
```

This makes sheets whose name begins with `thing`, get the result of `myCustomFunction` into cell `I1`.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem.

This is how I am doing it atm, but its not the best solution. I am looking for a better one.

If any value at sheet Prices and column D changes.
Meaning if any cell value changes in the whole column it updates the custom function value.

```
//Search Price sheet with the given name. Return price. dummy param updates google ss once the "Prices" sheet values changed.
function searchPrice(price,dummy)
{
  var SPREADSHEET_NAME = "Prices";
  var SEARCH_COL_IDX = 2;
  var RETURN_COL_IDX = 3;
  var values = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(SPREADSHEET_NAME).getDataRange().getValues();
  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; i++)
  {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[SEARCH_COL_IDX] == price)
    {
      return row[RETURN_COL_IDX];
    }
  }
}
```

This is how you call it =searchPrice(B8,Prices!D:D)

Just give your custom function a dummy param. It doesn't do anything in the custom function.